# VTune Amplifier XE 2015 architecural anaylsis

Tags: profiling, cpu-architecture, instructions, intel-vtune

I recently downloaded the VTune Amplifier XE 2015 to profile applications.

For analysis, I want to profile in terms of both architectural and micro-architectural events.  I found that it is possible to get the micro-architectural analysis when starting a New Analysis, but was not able to find how to get the Architectural analysis (Eg: store instructions retired, load instructions retired, near call instructions, etc)

Is there  way to get the architectural analysis ?

Thanks for the help and the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- What you look for wrt **Load/Store instr retired** is available under *Microarchitecture Analysis > CPU Specific Analysis > your_CPU_type analysis > Memory Access*  (you may also get more detailed info using *Analysis Type > Microarchitecture Analysis >  General Exploration*).
- What you look for wrt **Near Call** is available under "Analysis Types > Advanced Hotspots" (there is a dedicated column for it in the middle of bottom-up).
- If you want to combine both sources of information, you may have to set-up your own "Custom Analysis" (very last item in analysis types tree in VTune).

Trying to differentiate "architectural analysis" vs. "microarchitectural analysis" is sometimes counterproductive, especially taking in mind that every next processor has its own unique PMU capabilities, where *_RETIRED events analysis is replaced by *_UOPS_RETIRED analysis for given CPU type.

For better load/store PMU analysis understanding you may want to quickly look through this discussion: https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/topic/280684